# I cant seem to get any response when attempting to run these two functions simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a final project for my python class and I have been desperately attempting to get these two processes to run at the same time, but when I run them I get no responses from either functions.

```
import threading, time
count = 0
clock = 1200 - count
def f1():

    while True:
        if count < 1200:
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            print(count)
        else:
            exit()

def f2():
   pass

threading.Thread(target=f1).start()
threading.Thread(target=f2).start()
```

Apologies if this is a silly question, I just cant seem to get anything to work and I just want to be able to take reference from the timer in the first function from the second function during play. 
Also to give some context, in the second function I am creating an escape room that will use the first function to check how much time they have left to escape.

Basically now I incorporated a section to the second part of my function to test and see if I could pull information from my first function to the second. This time both programs worked well simultaneously but due to my noob level knowledge when it comes to python, I wasn't sure how I would be able to get the updated version of count from my first function.

```
import threading, time
count = 0
def f1():
    global count
    while True:
        if count < 1200:
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            print(count)
        else:
            exit()
    return count


def f2():
    clock = 1200 - count
    p = 1
    while True:
        while p == 1:
            if p == 1:
                print("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>")
                print("It seems you wont be able to get any clear information without inspecting each thing")
                print("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>")
                time.sleep(5)
                desk = input("What do you do?")

            if desk.lower() == ("inspect clock"):
                print("You look up at the digital clock on the wall.")
                print("Glowing red, the clock continues to count down.")
                print("You seem to have", clock," seconds left")

            elif desk.lower() == ("inspect box"):
                print("After clear inspection of the box, you note that each of the buttons are a color of the rainbow")
                print("However, you also notice that each button has a number written on it.")
                print("The numbers and colors are as follows:")
                print("'Red, 4 / Orange, 3 / Yellow, 6 / Green, 5 / Blue, 2 / Purple, 1")

            elif desk.lower() == ("inspect paper"):
                import Rainbow
                print("Click the window to stop looking at the paper")

            elif desk.lower() == ("get up"):
                print("You find it impossible to move due to the chains wrapped around your legs.")
                print("There is also a lock sitting on your lap, preventing you from removing the chain.")

            elif desk.lower() == ("inspect lock"):
                print("It is a lock, no key attached though")

            elif desk.lower() ==("solve box"):
                box = input("What is the solution? R=4,O=3,Y=6,G=5,B=2,P=1")
                if box.lower() == ("43621"):
                    p = 2
                else:
                    print("The box does nothing, mustve been the wrong combination")


            else:
                print("Invalid input. Retry.")



threading.Thread(target=f1).start()
threading.Thread(target=f2).start()
```

Basically I want to be able to use the input "inspect clock" and get the updated count from the timer function. This is probably a silly question, apologies if it is.

Comment: You have a local and a global version of the `count` variable.

Comment: Literally I just made that realization like 30 seconds ago, I am retarded. 
Also, now I have the issue that I cant seem to access the count variable from the first function to use within the second function

Answer (score 0):

You need to let Python know that you're referring to the global `count` in `pass`.  To do this, you just need to use the `global` keyword. Try this:

```
import threading, time
count = 0
clock = 1200 - count
def f1():
    global count
    while True:
        if count < 1200:
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            print(count)
        else:
            exit()

def f2():
   pass

threading.Thread(target=f1).start()
threading.Thread(target=f2).start()
```

When you reference count in `f2`, you do not need to use the global keyword. You can test this out by replacing `f2` with the following:

```
def f2():
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
       print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are worth avoiding, but the below at least demonstrates that the bulk of your code is correct. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `clock` so I commented it out. But this returns output from both functions.

```
import threading, time

count = 0
# clock = 1200 - count

def f1():
    global count
    while True:
        if count < 1200:
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            print(count)
        else:
            exit()

def f2():
    global count
    while True:
        print('f2():',count)
        time.sleep(1)

threading.Thread(target=f1).start()
threading.Thread(target=f2).start()
```

Comment: Alright well I hope you see this but I incorporated in an edit what the clock variable was for, I cant seem to figure out how to obtain the updated count for my second function.

Comment: There are a number of issues with your edit, but your reference to `clock` in the line you have will work.